# How to fill out an SKLabelNode with a specific color through animation?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sknode, sklabelnode

I've been searching the internet for a while now and I couldn't come up with any solution. 
I've created a SKLabelNode in my SpriteKit project which displays level numbers.

SKLabelNode:

```
    let levelLbl = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "LEMON-Bold")
    levelLbl.text = "1"
    levelLbl.fontSize = 100
    levelLbl.fontColor = .grey
    levelLbl.zPosition = 2
    levelLbl.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    levelLbl.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    levelLbl.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.height * 0.75)
    addChild(levelLbl)
```

Screenshot:
[Screenshot of my label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqVq1.jpg)

I want to fill up the number of my label smoothly with white color from the bottom to the top with an animation so that after x seconds the label is completely white. 
I don't want the color to fade in but rather to be filled up similar to a cup of water.

It would be amazing if someone could help me out here!

This is how far I came by using a SKCropNode. My problem is I don't know why I don't see an animation:

```
 func labelAnimation() {
    let levelLbl = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "LEMON-Bold")

    let blackRect = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: levelLbl.frame.width, height: levelLbl.frame.height))
    blackRect.fillColor = .grey
    blackRect.strokeColor = .grey
    blackRect.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: levelLbl.frame.height / 2)

    let whiteRect = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: levelLbl.frame.width, height: levelLbl.frame.height))
    whiteRect.fillColor = .white
    whiteRect.strokeColor = .white
    whiteRect.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -levelLbl.frame.height / 2)

    //Level Node
    levelNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    levelNode.addChild(blackRect)
    levelNode.addChild(whiteRect)

    //Mask Node
    levelLbl.text = "\(levelNr)"
    levelLbl.fontSize = 100
    levelLbl.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    levelLbl.verticalAlignmentMode = .center

    //Crop Node
    cropNode.addChild(levelNode)
    cropNode.maskNode = levelLbl
    cropNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    cropNode.zPosition = 5
    addChild(cropNode)

    //action
    let movelevelNode = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.height / 3), duration: 8)
    levelNode.run(movelevelNode)
}
```

Comment: In the picture, is the one in the separated from the background color? Or is the background color a part of something else aside from the one? I can't determine if your `levellbl` is just the one or the one and the gray background.

Comment: My levelLbl is just the one in the middle.

Comment: Not tried, but I think something like this would work: Take the label size and make two rectangles of that size with the initial and final colors.  Stack them vertically in an `SKNode` called, e.g., `level`.  Make an `SKCropNode` containing `level` as a child.  Run an action to move `level` in an appropriate direction over x seconds.  Use the label node as the `maskNode` of the crop node.

Comment: I did everything and it works so far but when I assign the `levelLbl` as a mask for the crop node everything disappears.

Comment: @bg2b is it possible to turn the number of the `levelLbl` into a path, then use that path to create an `SKSpriteNode` which then looks exactly like the label and use that SKSpriteNode as the `maskNode` for the `SKCropNode` ?

Comment: @bg2b I wrote everything that I did so far in my question

Comment: @bg2b I remove the line `addChild(levelLbl)` and know everything works perfectly. Thanks a lot!